# Central Limit Theorem, when to take complement?

Tags: probability

I'm confused as when to take the complement of the Central Limit Theorem. For example, in this question:

[image]

$P(Y\ge 60)$, The solution is $1 - P(Z > 2)$,

[image]

Where as for this question, $P (S_{100} > 5200)$, we don't take the complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first problem, the random variable $X$ has mean $2$ and variance $1$. It follows that the random variable $Y$ has mean $72$ and variance $36$. Thus $Y$ has standard deviation $6$.

The random variable $Y$ has roughly normal distribution. We have
$$\Pr(Y\ge 60)\approx \Pr\left(Z\ge\frac{60-72}{6}\right).$$

So we want the probability that $Z$ is $\ge -2$.

Many tables of the standard normal do not give information about $\Pr(Z\ge z)$ for **negative** $z$. To deal with that, we use the symmetry of the density function of the standard normal about $z=0$. By symmetry, $\Pr(Z\ge -2)=\Pr(Z\le 2)=1-\Pr(Z\gt 2)$.

So the answer to your question is that when $z$ is negative, we cannot make direct use of the most common type of table of the standard normal.

Comment: Thank you so much that cleared a lot of things up!

Comment: You are welcome. What I wrote is nowadays essentially obsolete, since it is more and more common to use software rather than tables to evaluate such probabilities. Saving space (paper) is no longer of importance.